# How to remove close button from the Stripe Popup dynamically

Tags: wordpress, modal-dialog, stripe.js

I am working with Stripe code section, my requirement is to remove the "Close Button" from Stripe Modal Dynamically. Stripe popup is coming in Iframe on my page load. So how can i remove the button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove close button on stripe popup be css

```
.Checkout.is-desktop .Header-navClose {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Comment: No this is not working as the Stripe Modal is loaded in iframe on page after some time. So elements are not bounded.